# jQuery detect which id is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to start function on document ready and also on button click. If button clicked, then need to detect which id clicked.

To start function I did

```
process_add_to_chart();// this is for document ready
$( '[id^="button_add_to_cart_"]' ).click(function(){
process_add_to_chart();
});
```

Then

```
function process_add_to_chart(){   }
```

Function starts, but how to get attr of id?

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

does not work. Get undefined

Ah, sorry, seems must define global id inside

```
$( '[id^="button_add_to_cart_"]' ).click(function(){   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('[id^="button_add_to_cart_"]').click(function(){
   process_add_to_chart(this);
});

function process_add_to_chart(obj){
  if(obj != null){
   var id = $(obj).attr('id');
  }
}
```

Pass clicked element object reference to your function.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/9y8bLg22/

Answer (score 1):

Because you call `process_add_to_char` inside the real handler (`function () { ... })`), you lose the original `this` "context" (the clicked element), and `this` is now the `window` object.

So, you need to bind the handler like this:

```
$( '[id^="button_add_to_cart_"]' ).click(process_add_to_chart);
```

And then, `this` will be the clicked element.

---

Another way is to use the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method to pass the `this` argument to the inner function, like this:

```
$( '[id^="button_add_to_cart_"]' ).click(function(){
     process_add_to_chart.call(this);
});
```

---

For further reading: [JavaScript - The this keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html)